# java - how to open a program and detect when the program is closed

Tags: java

My main method opens an app and sets `running` to false after it has finished executing, the only problem is that I want to to set `running` to false only once the opened app has been closed. Is there any easy way to do this?

This is my code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
boolean running = true;
try {
    Process p = runtime.exec("open test.app");
    p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
running = false;
```

EDIT: What happens at the moment is it opens `test.app`, then it sets `running` to false even though the app is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `open` starts app and exits. So you still see something running, and java sees that process finished. I guessing you are doing it on MacOS. I've never touch Macs myself, but documentation for [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/open.1.html) command states that you need pass `-W` option to force `open` wait for app termination: `Process p = runtime.exec("open -W test.app");`

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I am running on mac and I didn't even think to look at the man page for `open`. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Detects when a process is finished and invokes the associated listeners.
 */
public class ProcessExitDetector extends Thread {

    /** The process for which we have to detect the end. */
    private Process process;
    /** The associated listeners to be invoked at the end of the process. */
    private List<ProcessListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ProcessListener>();

    /**
     * Starts the detection for the given process
     * @param process the process for which we have to detect when it is finished
     */
    public ProcessExitDetector(Process process) {
        try {
            // test if the process is finished
            process.exitValue();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The process is already ended");
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException exc) {
            this.process = process;
        }
    }

    /** @return the process that it is watched by this detector. */
    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // wait for the process to finish
            process.waitFor();
            // invokes the listeners
            for (ProcessListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.processFinished(process);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    /** Adds a process listener.
     * @param listener the listener to be added
     */
    public void addProcessListener(ProcessListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    /** Removes a process listener.
     * @param listener the listener to be removed
     */
    public void removeProcessListener(ProcessListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
...
processExitDetector = new ProcessExitDetector(program);
processExitDetector .addProcessListener(new ProcessListener() {
    public void processFinished(Process process) {
        System.out.println("The program has finished.");
    }
});
processExitDetector.start();
```

**Source(s)**:
[Detecting Process Exit in Java](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/detecting-process-exit-in-java/)

Comment: I tried that and it still has the same effect. It says it has finished but the opened app is still running. I've set program equal to `runtime.exec("open test.app")` so that may have something to do with it...

Comment: yup, 'open' will start an app and immediately return.